# HTML Numeric Entities Not Working in Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: google-maps, csv

I've got a CSV to upload to a Google Map I'm building. According to this [Maps Engine Support Page](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/1247807?hl=en) numeric HTML entities are allowed. I switched all my string commas to `&#44;`, but they show up literally as `&#44;`. I checked a couple other entities and they also did not display properly. Is this feature no longer offered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&#44;` should still been supported. I used it for an info window in jsfiddle, and all the commas are abled to be displayed.

You can check out this link for my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/42ues6ys/

Comment: Could it be because I'm just using the web interface? i.e. going to google.com/mymaps and uploading data? Am I too much of an amateur?

Comment: when you upload your data in the google.com/mymaps, you are entering plain text, it will probably escape the HTML entities. But if you do it in HTML, the HTML entities will be displayed.

Comment: So I need to go with the JavaScript API?

Comment: Yes, you will need JavaScript API instead of entering plain text.